# saving/sharing a String in xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, storyboard

i need to save a string within my application but i dont want to create a plist just for saving 1 string is there any other way to do so? im using storyboard. i tried segue but it didn't work

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
   {
   if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString: @"modal"])
   {
      ViewController *vc = (ViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
      vc.subject = self.subject;
   }
}
```

Comment: Which string exactly and where do you need to use the string? I see you are setting subject on `ViewController` (which I assume is your subclass of UIViewController). If you just want it to persist between controllers without passing it you could store it in `NSUserDefaults` assuming it's small (a few kilobytes or so)

Comment: actually its just a one word string hahaha

Comment: Yeah then stroring it in the `NSUserDefaults` like I and answer suggested will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If u can to use the string any where in the project just create a extern variable like this way.

In AppDelegate.h

```
extern NSString *stringObject;
```

In AppDelegate.m

```
NSString *stringObject;
```

U can use the stringObject any where in the project.

Comment: i tried n it didnt work i got this error

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_subjects", referenced from:

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "I need to save a string within my applicaion"? Do you just want to pass the string to your destination ViewController?

If that's the case, you could define a new property in your destination ViewController (assuming you know which one it is)

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *myProperty;
```

And then

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
   {
   if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString: @"modal"])
   {
      [segue.destinationViewController setMyProperty:self.myProperty];
   }
}
```

If you want your string to be accessible from anywhere in the application, you can save it to the user defaults quite easily :

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:myProperty forKey:@"myPropertyKeyName"];
```

You can get it back later :

```
NSString *mySavedProperty= [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]stringForKey:@"myPropertyKeyName"];
```

Comment: i need it to be universal in the app so any view controller can use that string

Comment: Then the NSUserDefaults solution I suggested will work just fine.